# Trying to define a function with a loop in ruby, and I'm getting an error where there isn't a function

Tags: arrays, ruby, json, sorting, reddit

I wrote a program to extract all (over 1000) the comments from a reddit post, and I'm having trouble defining a function.

The program:

```
require "rubygems"
require "json"
require "net/http"
require "uri"
require 'open-uri'
require 'neatjson'

#The URL, which changes.
url = ("https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/46n0zc.json")

#Sets up the JSON reader.
result = JSON.parse(open(url).read)
post = result[0]["data"]["children"]
children = result[1]["data"]["children"]

#Sets up the base location.
base = ("https://www.reddit.com" + post[0]["data"]["permalink"].to_s)

#Sets up the arrays.
mainIDs = Array.new
reIDs = Array.new

#Collects the main jsons.
children.each do |child|
 if child["data"].has_key? "body" 
  mainIDs.push(child["data"]["id"].to_s)
 end
end
mainINT = mainIDs.count

#Collects the remaining.
children.each do |child|
 if child["data"].has_key? "children"
  reIDs = child["data"]["children"]
 end
end
remainINT = reIDs.count


puts "Main Comments:   " + mainINT.to_s
puts "Total Comments:  " + (mainINT + remainINT).to_s


#Divides the page.
puts ("__" * 50)
puts ("\n")

#Creates a function for collection.
def printAllComments(array, comINT)
     for i in array do i
       url = base + i
        puts "Post URL:               " + url
        result = JSON.parse(open(url).read)
        children = result[1]["data"]["children"]
        int = comINT
        for i in children do child
        if child["data"].has_key? "body" 
          puts "Comment Number:       " + int.to_s
          puts "Author:               " + child["data"]["author"]
          puts "Body:                 " + neatBD(child["data"]["body"].to_s)
          puts "ID:                   " + child["data"]["id"]
          puts "Ups:                  " + child["data"]["ups"].to_s
          puts "\n\n"
          int += 1
        end
    end
end
end


printAllComments(mainINT, 1)
```

The "Creates a function for collection" is where the error is. When I run this, I get:

```
Main Comments:   64
Total Comments:  1676
____________________________________________________________________________________________________

007----extractallredditpostcomments.rb:51:in `printAllComments': undefined method `each' for 64:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
    from 007----extractallredditpostcomments.rb:72:in `<main>'
```

When I *should* be getting the first 64 comments from the main array, instead it just breaks after it prints the line. What's weird is that the error is on line 51, and line 51 is the:

```
url = base + i
```

there's no 'each' function there.

What am I missing?

Comment: I doubt it can be reproduced. Where does `base` in line 51 come from? The local variable `base` defined outside is inaccessible. Or, `base` might be referring to a method defined in one of the libraries.

Comment: What construction is `for i in array do i` and `for i in children do child`?

Answer (score 0):

`for i in array do` is equivalent to `array.each do |i|`. If `array` is not, actually, an array, you will get the error you are getting. Proof:

```
for i in 64 do puts i end
# NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for 64:Fixnum
```

Stylistically... no Rubyist uses `for`; everyone uses `each` directly.

Comment: @sawa: `for i in array do` is in OP's code, one line above `url = base + i`. And there is no explicit `each` that could throw that error. Furthermore, `mainINT.to_s` printed as `64`, `mainINT` being the value being passed as `array`.

Comment: @Amandan `Stylistically... no Rubyist uses for; everyone uses each directly.`: Except of course for the rare cases where one relies on the difference in scoping between the two. Though most Ruby style-guides discourage that.

Comment: But `mainINT` *is* an array: It has 64 values, the comment IDs.

Comment: No, `mainINT = mainIDs.count`: it is a number.

Answer (score 0):

so there are a couple items that I would point out.

First the loop syntax feels a bit funny. If you want to access each element of the array I would use `array.each do |item|`, same of the inner loop `children.each do |child|`.

Next you are actually passing the `mainINT` instead of `mainIDs` which is an int, not an array. This is what was throwing the error you asked about.

Lastly you are trying to reference `base` from within your method but it doesn't exist within the method's scope, try passing it into the method or making the variable global with `@base`.

Changing these few items I was able to get one URL to print out and then ran into an issue with parsing the JSON but I will leave that to you. This should hopefully get you moving forward.

Patrick